# MongoDB URI connection environment variable of password not working

Tags: mongodb

MongoDB URI connection environment variable of password not working.

```
const uri =
  "mongodb+srv://ronnlidd:...@cluster0-qfs54.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true";
```

With the 3 dots being the letters of my password it works fine, but if I try to do this (dotenv is installed and variable created in seperate file):

```
const uri =
  `mongodb+srv://ronnlidd:${process.env.MONGODB_PASSWORD}@cluster0-qfs54.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true`;
```

... I get the following error message:

```
{ Error: querySrv ENOTFOUND _mongodb._tcp.cluster0.mongodb.net
  at QueryReqWrap.onresolve [as oncomplete] (dns.js:197:19)
  errno: 'ENOTFOUND',
  code: 'ENOTFOUND',
  syscall: 'querySrv',
  hostname: '_mongodb._tcp.cluster0.mongodb.net' }
C:\CodingProjects\nodepractice\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongo_client.js:233
    throw new MongoError('MongoClient must be connected before calling MongoClient.prototype.db');
    ^

MongoError: MongoClient must be connected before calling MongoClient.prototype.db
    at MongoClient.db (C:\CodingProjects\nodepractice\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongo_client.js:233:11)
    at client.connect.err (C:\CodingProjects\nodepractice\index.js:52:10)
    at err (C:\CodingProjects\nodepractice\node_modules\mongodb\lib\utils.js:411:14)
    at executeCallback (C:\CodingProjects\nodepractice\node_modules\mongodb\lib\utils.js:401:25)
    at err (C:\CodingProjects\nodepractice\node_modules\mongodb\lib\operations\mongo_client_ops.js:285:21)
    at parseFn (C:\CodingProjects\nodepractice\node_modules\mongodb\lib\operations\mongo_client_ops.js:197:21)
    at QueryReqWrap.dns.resolveSrv [as callback] (C:\CodingProjects\nodepractice\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\uri_parser.js:56:21)
    at QueryReqWrap.onresolve [as oncomplete] (dns.js:197:10)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

The context of the code is this:
Above URI being defined:

```
const MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient;
```

Below URI being defined:

```
const client = new MongoClient(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true });
```

Thanks.

Comment: Main error: MongoClient must be connected before calling MongoClient.prototype.db